# Node.js testing server with telnet - set Linemode

Tags: node.js, telnet

could someone advise me how to set linemode to telnet testing? I googled a lot, but unfortunately I wasn't sucessful. 
I have this super easy code

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function(c) {
  console.log('socket opened');
  c.setEncoding('utf8');
  c.on('end', function() {
    console.log('connection/socket closed');
  });
  c.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Data:'+data);
    c.write('Answer:'+data);
    // c.end(); // close socket/conection
  });
});

server.listen(8124, function() { // start server (port 8124)
  console.log('server started');
});
```

but the testing looks like this:

**client:**

```
Microsoft Telnet> open localhost 8124
Answer:dAnswer:daAnswer:atAnswer:taAnswer:a
```

**server:**

```
C:\Users\Laura\node server.js
server started
socket opened
Data:d
Data:a
Data:t
Data:a
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to get the telnet input like as below

```
Answer: a
Answer: b
Answer: c
```

then you need to send both `\r is carriage return` with `line feed (\n)`. so your code should be like bellow

```
var server = net.createServer(function(c) {
    console.log('socket opened');
    c.setEncoding('utf8');
    c.on('end', function() {
        console.log('connection/socket closed');
    });
    c.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('Data:'+data);
        c.write('\r\nAnswer:');
        // c.end(); // close socket/conection
    });
});
```